# wp_list_categories only list for current top parent that is viewed

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following function to display a sidebar category tree:

```
            $args = array (
               'title_li'           => __( '' ),
               'hide_empty'         => 0,
               'show_count'         => 1,
               'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
               'child_of'           => 0
            );
            wp_list_categories( $args );
```

A single post is attached to multiple parents and subcategories like this:

- Parent A (active)

  - sub-category
  - sub-category (active)
- Parent B (active)

  - sub-category
  - sub-category (active)

**Issue:**
Currently the sidebar displays a full tree of parent to subcategories (parent A and parent B), I would like to achieve it to show only the current parent that it was navigated from (Parent A > sub-category (active)) that is also the permalink address. It should also work dynamically without a manual ID insertion to the function

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$term =  $wp_query->queried_object;
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'your_taxonomy';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' .$term->name .   '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently solved with using:

```
            $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
            $catid = $category[0]->cat_ID;
            $top_level_cat = smart_category_top_parent_id ($catid);
            $args = array (
               'title_li'           => __( '' ),
               'hide_empty'         => 0,
               'show_count'         => 1,
               'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
               'child_of'           => $top_level_cat 
            );
            wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Getting the top level category ID dynamically and adding it to child_of parameter

Answer (score 0):

you can write/check this code on archive-product.php to show only parent categories on page. While show the child categories on parent categories page.

```
<?php
$term123 = get_queried_object();
$slug=$term123->slug;
$parent_id  =$term123->parent;
$child_id=$term123->term_id;



$taxonomy_name ='product_cat';
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy_name ); //Get all the terms
$termchildren  = get_term_children(  $child_id, $taxonomy_name  );

// Parent Categories
foreach ($terms as $term) { 
    // Check and see if the termxxxxx is a top-level parent. If so, display it.
    $parent = $term->parent;
     if ( $parent=='0' ) {
     ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
}
// Child Categories
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $termc = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    if ($termc->parent == $child_id) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($termc->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $termc->name; ?></a></li>
   <?php
   } 
}
```